# not able to select topic in rviz

Tags: rviz, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started with introduction to working with laserscanner data tutorials:

as it says i executed the following commands in terminal:

roscore in a terminal

### then again

```
$ rosbag play laser.bag[ INFO] [1331111093.757680745]: Opening laser.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
 [RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1275001525.634246   Duration: 41.420635 / 41.431989    
Done.
root@arun-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~# rostopic list -v | grep sensor_msgs/LaserScan
root@arun-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~# rosrun rviz rviz
```

---

in rviz i could not find the laserscan or /tilt_scan topic.
i have inserted the rviz i got after rosrun rviz rviz

can anyone tell me why i'm not able to see the topics list and visualize laserdata in rviz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30457/not-able-to-select-topic-in-rviz/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you wait for the rosbag to finish playing and exit it will no longer be published.

I would run rosbag in a separate terminal and pause it while you get rviz setup, or run rostopic list.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0